# How do I shoehorn text in a <div> tag? (using jQuery validate & AdminLTE template)

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How do I shoehorn an error message between `<div></div>` tags?

HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>New Job Code (required)</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add_job_code_name" name="add_job_code_name" />
    <label for="add_job_code_name" hidden><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> <div>** Add error message here **</div></label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Default start time</label>
    <input type="text" id="add_job_code_start_time" name="add_job_code_start_time" class="form-control" />
    <label for="add_job_code_start_time" hidden><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> <div>** Add error message here **</div></label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Default end time</label>
    <input type="text" id="add_job_code_end_time" name="add_job_code_end_time" class="form-control" />
    <label for="add_job_code_end_time" hidden><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> <div>** Add error message here **</div></label>
</div>
```

jQuery validate code:

```
,errorPlacement: function(strError, objElement) {
    objElement.closest("div").addClass("has-error"); // color label and field border red; works nicely
    objElement.closest("div").children("div").innerHTML(strError); // shoehorn error message; this is the problem code.
}
```

If it helps, I am using the AdminLTE template.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how the errorPlacement function is being called, it's hard to say for sure. But it's likely simply not finding the container that you're trying manipulate.

Maybe give your error message `<div>` an ID. Then you can reference it directly.

HTML:

```
<div id="error-message"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#error-message').text('Your error message');
```

Comment: I'm using the jQuery validate plug-in to validate my form. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>New Job Code (required)</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add_job_code_name" name="add_job_code_name" />
    <label for="add_job_code_name" hidden><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> <div class="error-div">* I want an error message here *</div></label>
</div>
```

## jQuery validate code:

```
,errorPlacement: function(strError, objElement) {
    $('.error-div').addClass("has-error"); // color label and field border red; works nicely
    $('.error-div').HTML(strError); // shoehorn error message; this is the problem code.
}
```